# Reaction between iron oxides to form magnetite

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-control

In the notes of a course it is indicated that the reaction of formation of magnetite from iron oxides can only take place if the partial pressure of oxygen is higher than 1 nanobar.

$\ce{FeO}$ + $\ce{Fe2O3}$ $\rightarrow$ $\ce{Fe3O4}$

I have tried to search in the scientific literature for the origin of this fact, but I have not found anything. I assume it will be a kinetic limitation, since the reaction is thermodynamically favored at any temperature. Am I correct?

Comment: ..but not in any oxygen partial pressure due $\ce{2 Fe3O4 <=> 6 FeO + O2}$.

Comment: @Poutnik And, from this equilibrium that you propose, how could you calculate the minimum pressure for the magnetite formation reaction to take place?

Comment: You cannot without more data.

Comment: What data would I need? I would be interested in learning how to perform such calculations. @Poutnik

Comment: The is not so simple. You might want to look at the [equilibrium phase diagram.](https://imgur.com/k3CCeMf). Moreover, [$\ce{FeO}$ is thermodynamically unstable below 575 °C and disproportionate: $\ce{4FeO ->[\Delta] Fe + Fe3O4}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(II)_oxide)